Conversion of Tensorflow object detection annotation file to model input
I am new to Tensorflow and ML; hence, following the tutorials for object detection using YOLOv8.
I am simplifying the steps but the annotations are parsed via the below approach:
output_spec = {
    "images": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 3)),
    "bounding_boxes": {
        "boxes": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4)),
        "classes": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,)),
    },
}

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, output_signature=output_spec)

train_data = data.ragged_batch(BATCH_SIZE)

If I pass the train_data to the model.fit but it throws the below error
Failed to convert elements of tf.RaggedTensor(values=tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("yolov8_detector_1/functional_1/rescaling_1/Add:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("RaggedFromVariant_2/RaggedTensorFromVariant:1", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)), row_splits=Tensor("RaggedFromVariant_2/RaggedTensorFromVariant:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.

The issue is fixed if I process the train_data using the below:
augmenter = keras.Sequential(
    layers=[
        keras_cv.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", bounding_box_format="rel_xyxy"),
        keras_cv.layers.JitteredResize(
            target_size=(640, 640),
            scale_factor=(0.75, 1.3),
            bounding_box_format="rel_xyxy",
        ),
    ]
)
train_data = train_data.map(augmenter, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

I really do not want to apply any augmentation and plus I have a similar issue with the validation data. The tutorial uses the following but my images are already 640x640
inference_resizing = keras_cv.layers.Resizing(
    640, 640, pad_to_aspect_ratio=True, bounding_box_format="rel_xyxy"
)
val_data = val_data.map(inference_resizing, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

Could you please let me know how I can convert the object data I parse from the annotation to model input (which I believe must be a tensor)? Do I have to use ragged tensor at all for YoloV8 object detection?
